# Would tags such as "ultrafilters" or "Stone-Cech compactification" be too specific?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've noticed that one question was recently tagged [filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter). (It is the only question having this tag at the moment.)

I was thinking about a few related tags, which might perhaps be useful; but I wanted to ask about the opinion of other users before creating any of these tags. (I might be biased, since I am interested in these topics. And of course we have 5 tags limit, so we should not overtag.) And it was also advised [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2826/): *If you are not sure whether a tag belongs, bring it to Meta.*

> Do you think that tags like
>   [filters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters),
>   [ultrafilters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultrafilters),
>   [compactification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactification) or
>   [stone-cech-compactification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stone-cech-compactification) 
>   would be too specific?

---

Some arguments why I think these tags would be reasonable:

- If a whole book was written about some topic, perhaps  this topic would deserve its own tag: This true for both [Stone-Čech compactification](http://books.google.com/books?id=KYXgdiegKDsC) and [ultrafilters](http://books.google.com/books?id=vLxPAQAAIAAJ).
- At MO they have [filters](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/filters) (48 questions),
  [ultrafilters](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ultrafilters) (8 questions),
  [compactification](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/compactification) (16 questions),
  [stone-cech](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/stone-cech) (3 questions).
- There are already several question at this site, which could fit these tags. Just try to search for [ultrafilter](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=ultrafilter) or [Stone-Cech compactification](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Stone+Cech+compactification)

---

Aside note: Do you think it would be reasonable to make one big thread for questions related to proposed or newly-created tags, in the same way as we did for [Tag merging and synonyms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms) ?

---

EDIT: I believe 6 upvotes for Asaf's post can be understood as support for his suggestion, which was [compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactness) tag and one common tag for filters and ultrafilters. He has already started [compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactness). <s>I've edited tag-wiki for filter.</s> Now Asaf also created tag [filters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters) and added tag-wiki. I'll try to add a few questions in the next days, so that the tag is not automatically deleted for having no questions. (This will also have the effect that a few more people will be aware of this tag, since they will see it used on the main page.)

<s>I am not entirely sure about the preference of singular/plural in tag names; however I was not able to create [filters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters) tag, I've got the following warning: *Creating the new tag [filters] is not allowed since the tag [filter] already exists. If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.*</s>

Comment: I think that [filter] should be renamed to [filters].

Comment: I agree - that's why I wanted to remove [tag:filter] and create [tag:filters] instead. But the software did not allow me to do this.

Comment: Let us try, untag and then re-tag. I untagged, but it may take a few minutes before the system notices that. **Edit:** I think that the tag wiki may be preventing the dissipation the [filter] tag.

Comment: I've put the last version of tag-wiki and excerpt here: http://pastebin.com/xm8XKUrq So we will not lose it if the tag is deleted. However, I don't think tag-wiki matters; IIRC [tag:algebra] tag disappeared and it had non-empty tag wiki.

Comment: Very good, let us wait a day or so.

Comment: @Asaf It seems that empty tags are deleted [once a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags).
See also [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2829/)

Comment: Let the games begin!

Comment: Just a suggestion for tag editing. 
I think it's good to include the relevant meta thread in edit summary, so that the people who look at the history of revisions know what's goging on. 
I was doing so e.g. for algebra retagging, see e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/30173/revisions) and also for these two new tags, example is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/96051/revisions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I remember once walking in the library and seeing huge books on a single molecular structure. I know that there are books over books written on Mozart's symphonies, etc.

The fact that something has a book, a handbook, or even a whole publishing company devoted to it has little to do with the question whether or not this site should have a specific tag.

Remember that this is not quite the research site, so the fact there are books on the topic need not imply that there are enough non-research questions to make the tag useful. For example see [ordered-fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordered-fields) which currently host about five questions.

With this breath I should also say that I am in favor of [filters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters) **or** [ultrafilters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultrafilters), this is an exclusive or. Both would be too much in my opinion. Compactification seems reasonable, but Stone-Cech seems over-specific. Instead both, however, I suggest [compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactness) which would also host questions about compactness in general.

Comment: So the [tag:compactness] tag would include compact spaces, locally compacts spaces, compactifications and other related topics, correct?

Comment: @Martin: Yes. More or less.

Comment: @Martin: I kicked off the compactness tag, I have to admit that it has been a while that I was thinking that this tag is suitable (I was thinking about a filter related one too, but less often).

Comment: Thanks for starting the tag. Do you think it would be useful to include in the tag wiki, that it is intended for related topics (like local compactness, compactification), too?

Comment: @Martin: Probably, I wanted to get the tag wiki started too but I didn't know how far to take it. There is *so much* to say about compactness and its related topics...

Comment: I've noticed only now that you've mentioned variants of compactness and compactifications in tag excerpt. I think that is sufficient. (For some reason I only looked at tag-wiki and did not notice that tag-excerpt is different.)

Comment: FWIW: I agree with the use of a more general compactness tag as Asaf proposed.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm doubtful about whether a new tag is appropriate, I apply the following tests:

- Can I imagine at least two other users independently deciding that this tag is worth using or searching for? (This is a very weak test but any tag that it rejects should definitely not be used.)
- Will any question that falls under this tag already contain this tag in the text? In other words, is this tag already a viable **search term** for any questions it might apply to? If so, there's no reason for the additional information in the tag. (I think 
  [stone-cech-compactification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stone-cech-compactification) fails this test.)

I can imagine objections to the second test and probably there are tags that fail it that I would still use for other reasons, but I think it's not a bad guideline.

Comment: If you search "compactness" you have ~450 results; if you search "compact" you get >2000 results. I haven't began looking for variants (compactification; locally compact; etc.) but I believe that your second test supports my idea for a [compactification] tag.

Comment: Well, the fact that questions about filters and ultrafilters can be found using the keywords is not the same thing as tags - for example it's not possible to add it between favorite tags. I agree about Stone-Cech compactification being too specific and starting more general tag [tag:compactness] seems to me a good solution. What do you think about [tag:filters] tag?

Comment: This is no longer relevant - since I agreed that Stone-Cech compactification is too specific topic to deserve its own tag. But out of curiosity I've tried whether I am able to find questions which might get this tag and do not contain the words *Stone-Cech compactification* (=your second test). Examples:
[Points in $\beta\omega$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98716/), [Addition on ultrafilters is non-commutative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87109/) and
[Set of ultrafilters $\beta\mathbb N-\mathbb N$ is not separable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84091/).