# New tags: [gaussian-elimination]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Should there be a tag for Gaussian elimination?

It’s a reasonably common question topic, presumably since it’s a standard part of the math curriculum at many universities (and also lends itself particularly well to homework problems).  [Searching for it](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=gaussian+elimination) shows over 500 existing questions — more questions than about [6/7 of existing tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?page=5&tab=popular) have.

The previous meta question [New tags: when?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/new-tags-when) unfortunately doesn’t give much guidance, apart from “if not sure, ask Meta”.

(Prompt for asking: I just asked [a new question about Gaussian elimination/Smith normal form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612449/algebraic-solutions-for-last-step-of-gaussian-elimination-smith-norma-form), and couldn’t find any tags better than the *very* wide-ranging [matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices) and [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra).)

Comment: I think this would be a good tag (especially if there are 500 existing questions with this topic, which is a lot in my opinion).

Comment: If a tag is created, will [Gauss-Jordan elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination) be a synonym? (So that the people more familiar with the name *Jordan elimination* will see the tag if they start typing the word *Jordan*.)

Comment: I see that the tag ([tag:gaussian-elimination]) has been already created. It might be worth mentioning here.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: yep — after getting support from the earlier comment and answer, I created the tag and started by retagging a few existing questions.

Answer (score 7):

As you've said in your post, a search brings up [517 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=gaussian+elimination) related to Gaussian elimination. I concur that creating the tag would be a good idea, with the caveat that only a few questions should be edited to add the tag at a time (so as not to clutter the front page with dozens of old posts that are simply being retagged).